# Improve many ifs that returns enumeration with Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, code-cleanup

Of course, when we talk about number of ifs, we try to use the Strategy Pattern. But how about when I want to separate the conditions inside if().

For example, I am developing a game with many possibilites:

I have a class called Game. I check the method and return an enumeration.

```
if(TieByPoints()) {
  return Result.TieByPoints;
}
if(TieByTimeOver()) {
  return Result.TieByTimeOver;
}
if(JustOnePlayerWin()) {
  return Result.PlayerWin;
}
if(ManyPlayersWin()) {
  return Result.PlayerWin;
}
```

But many other possibilites/rules can be created.
So, is there a way to separate in different classes? Put these conditions in different places?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve, or the code smell you want to eliminate? It will help if you can explain what you dislike about this code.

Comment: If new rules emerge, I have to create new if conditions. So, is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained enough details to say with certainty, but one approach would be to use a registry pattern, where the registry holds result producers.

Something like

```java
public enum Result { None, TieByPoints, ... };

public class ResultSupplierRegistry {
  /** Singleton instance of registry. */
  public static final ResultProducerRegistry INSTANCE = new ResultSupplierRegistry();

  private final Map<Result, Supplier<Boolean>> resultSuppliers = new HashSet<>();

  private ResultSupplierRegistry() {}

  public void register(Result result, Supplier<Boolean> resultSupplier) {
    resultSuppliers.put(result, resultSupplier);
  }

  public Result getResult() {
    return resultSuppliers.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().get()).map(Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(Result.None);
  }
}
```

Now you need some initialization to populate the registry. I haven't taken any precautions about thread safety here. If the initialization can be by multiple threads, you'll need to fix that.

Comment: Great! I've never head about that. Thank you.